# removeClass, addClass works only for same/higher div then clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a weird problem. I'm using .removeClass and .addClass in my project. It's working fine, when you click firstly on lower card. (1,2,3,4), (2,3,4)... But when you once click on card > 1, then lower cards doesn't work any more. (2,3,4,1!,2!,3!,4,4,4,2!...). For better understanding I uploaded it on my web: **http://hdesign.comehere.cz/** Try to click on card 1,2,3,4 and then click on one of 1,2,3 - they doesn't work anymore. But if you click on 4, that will work. So basicly **works** card, whitch is **same** **or** **higher** then card **lastly** clicked. HERE IS A CODE:

```
<script>
//CARD1
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".icon_card1").click(function () {
        $(".card1bg").css('opacity', '1');
    });
    $(".icon_card1").click(function () {
        $(".card1_content").css('margin-left', '0%');
    });
    $(".card1_content_arrow").click(function () {
        $(".card1_content").css('margin-left', '-45%');
    });
    $(".card1_content_arrow").click(function () {
        $(".card1bg").css('opacity', '0');
    });
    $(".icon_card1").on('click', function() {
        $(".card1").removeClass('animace1back').addClass('animace1');
    });
    $(".card1_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card1").removeClass('animace1').addClass('animace1back');
    });
    $(".icon_card1").on('click', function() {
        $(".card2").removeClass('animace2back').addClass('animace2');
    });
    $(".card1_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card2").removeClass('animace2').addClass('animace2back');
    });
    $(".icon_card1").on('click', function() {
        $(".card3").removeClass('animace3back').addClass('animace3');
    });
    $(".card1_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card3").removeClass('animace3').addClass('animace3back');
    });
    $(".icon_card1").on('click', function() {
        $(".card4").removeClass('animace4back').addClass('animace4');
    });
    $(".card1_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card4").removeClass('animace4').addClass('animace4back');
    });
});
</script>
<script>
//CARD2
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".icon_card2").click(function () {
        $(".card2bg").css('opacity', '1');
    });
    $(".icon_card2").click(function () {
        $(".card2_content").css('margin-left', '0%');
    });
    $(".card2_content_arrow").click(function () {
        $(".card2_content").css('margin-left', '-45%');
    });
    $(".card2_content_arrow").click(function () {
        $(".card2bg").css('opacity', '0');
    });
    $(".icon_card2").on('click', function() {
        $(".card2").removeClass('animace5back').addClass('animace5');
    });
    $(".card2_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card2").removeClass('animace5').addClass('animace5back');
    });
    $(".icon_card2").on('click', function() {
        $(".card1").removeClass('animace6back').addClass('animace6');
    });
    $(".card2_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card1").removeClass('animace6').addClass('animace6back');
    });
    $(".icon_card2").on('click', function() {
        $(".card3").removeClass('animace7back').addClass('animace7');
    });
    $(".card2_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card3").removeClass('animace7').addClass('animace7back');
    });
    $(".icon_card2").on('click', function() {
        $(".card4").removeClass('animace8back').addClass('animace8');
    });
    $(".card2_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card4").removeClass('animace8').addClass('animace8back');
    });
});
</script>
<script>
//CARD3
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".icon_card3").click(function () {
        $(".card3bg").css('opacity', '1');
    });
    $(".icon_card3").click(function () {
        $(".card3_content").css('margin-left', '0%');
    });
    $(".card3_content_arrow").click(function () {
        $(".card3_content").css('margin-left', '-45%');
    });
    $(".card3_content_arrow").click(function () {
        $(".card3bg").css('opacity', '0');
    });
    $(".icon_card3").on('click', function() {
        $(".card3").removeClass('animace9back').addClass('animace9');
    });
    $(".card3_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card3").removeClass('animace9').addClass('animace9back');
    });
    $(".icon_card3").on('click', function() {
        $(".card1").removeClass('animace10back').addClass('animace10');
    });
    $(".card3_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card1").removeClass('animace10').addClass('animace10back');
    });
     $(".icon_card3").on('click', function() {
        $(".card2").removeClass('animace11back').addClass('animace11');
    });
    $(".card3_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card2").removeClass('animace11').addClass('animace11back');
    });
    $(".icon_card3").on('click', function() {
        $(".card4").removeClass('animace12back').addClass('animace12');
    });
    $(".card3_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card4").removeClass('animace12').addClass('animace12back');
    });
});
</script>
<script>
//CARD4
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".icon_card4").click(function () {
        $(".card4bg").css('opacity', '1');
    });
    $(".icon_card4").click(function () {
        $(".card4_content").css('margin-left', '0%');
    });
    $(".card4_content_arrow").click(function () {
        $(".card4_content").css('margin-left', '-45%');
    });
    $(".card4_content_arrow").click(function () {
        $(".card4bg").css('opacity', '0');
    });
    $(".icon_card4").on('click', function() {
        $(".card4").removeClass('animace13back').addClass('animace13');
    });
    $(".card4_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card4").removeClass('animace13').addClass('animace13back');
    });
    $(".icon_card4").on('click', function() {
        $(".card1").removeClass('animace14back').addClass('animace14');
    });
    $(".card4_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card1").removeClass('animace14').addClass('animace14back');
    });
    $(".icon_card4").on('click', function() {
        $(".card2").removeClass('animace15back').addClass('animace15');
    });
    $(".card4_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card2").removeClass('animace15').addClass('animace15back');
    });
    $(".icon_card4").on('click', function() {
        $(".card3").removeClass('animace16back').addClass('animace16');
    });
    $(".card4_content_arrow").on('click', function() {
        $(".card3").removeClass('animace16').addClass('animace16back');
    });
});
</script>
```

I guess, that I'm probably just re-writng some classes, but I just can't fugure whitch ones.

Comment: Could you use `.toggle()`?

Comment: Nope, because this will happen then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002851/css-animation-stuck?noredirect=1#comment57734075_35002851

Comment: That all depends on how you use it. See the answer or look at the 4th use: `.toggleClass( function [, state ] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to remove the classes you added on the click for "content_arrow"

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/31dze2qt/12/

```
        $(".card1").removeClass('animace1back animace6back animace10back animace14back');
        $(".card2").removeClass('animace2back animace5back animace11back animace15back');
        $(".card3").removeClass('animace3back animace7back animace9back animace16back');
        $(".card4").removeClass('animace4back animace8back animace12back animace13back');
```

deDelightedD0D is right, the code is very wrong, the binding should be done via "$this" and even the classes in css  needs a better structure

Answer (score 3):

You should really re-evaluate the logic here, you have a lot of duplicated code that is always going to be prone to errors and be a pain to debug.

I would suggest refactoring your code in such a way that you have one function or handler that acts on the elements. For example, you could give all your icon elements one class and bind the function to those elements, then use data attributes on the clicked elements to tell your function what element should be acted on and what classes should be toggled. With this approach you can add as many "cards" as needed without having to duplicate any javascript.

Here is a contrived example:

```js
$(".card-icon").on('click', function() {
        var $this=$(this);
        var $target=$($this.data('target'));
        var classes=$this.data('toggle-classes')
        $target.toggleClass(classes);
});
```

```css
.card-icon{
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#ccc;
  margin-bottom:10px;
 }

.card{
  height:100px;
  background-color:#ccc;
}


.animace1{
  width:300px;
}
.animace1back{
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon_card1 card-icon" data-target=".card1" data-toggle-classes="animace1back animace1">Click Me<div><br><br>
<div class="card1 card animace1"><div>
```